# Commitizen in gitlab pipeline

Tags: gitlab, cicd, commitizen

I have  to run Commitizen (cz bump) in gitlab pipeline. The problem is that firstly I have to run cz init and answer some questions. It is not possible in Pipeline. I received an error:

$ cz bump
[NO_VERSION_SPECIFIED]
Check if current version is specified in config file, like:
version = 0.4.3

I have also configured pyproject.toml but it doesn't help.
Solution form here doesn't work:
https://commitizen-tools.github.io/commitizen/tutorials/gitlab_ci/
Is there any solution to do this?

Comment: Do you have a `VERSION` file committed in your repo?

Comment: Hi, thank's for answer. I had a version file commited. The issue is solved.